# SQL Server symmetric key is lost, how to decrypt the data?

Tags: sql-server, encryption-symmetric

We are in a situation where  symmetric key and certificates are deleted, Is there any way can we decrypt the data?

We tried decrypting the data with same script which was used for creating the master key , certificate and symmetric keys.

Thanks
Vivek

Answer (score 2):

### By definition: **NO**

If it would be possible, it would mean the entire cryptography feature in SQL Server was useless. Can you define what `we lost the symmetric key and database certificate` means? Your only chance is if your understanding of 'lost' is incorrect and you still have the keys *somewhere*. SQL Server will refuse to drop keys if there is still data encrypted with them. Also it would worth defining what you understand by 'database certificate'.

Answer (score 0):

When using symmetric key to encrypt data, it uses a GUID for encryption. The GUID is generated automatically at the time of creatiion of symmetric key. So if u are trying to decrypt the data using newly generated symmetric key (same as old one), it will use the new `GUID` and as a result you cant decrypt it.

You can see this by using the following query: (Key_Guid is changing)

```
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY KeyTest WITH ALGORITHM = TRIPLE_DES  ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'EncryptPwd'

select * from sys.symmetric_keys

DROP SYMMETRIC KEY KeyTest 

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY KeyTest WITH ALGORITHM = TRIPLE_DES  ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'EncryptPwd'

select * from sys.symmetric_keys
```